# Setting the image of an ImageBox in a UserControl - c#

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I'm trying to set the image of a PictureBox on a FlowControl, however I can only access the background image property.

```
 if (File.Exists(filePath))
 {
      flowProd.Controls["picture_product"].BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(filePath);
 }
```

The `.Image` property isn't available to me. Does anyone know of a way for me to set the Image of my picture box?

Comment: what is the FlowControl? is in WPF or windows forms? are you using any components?

Comment: It's in Windows Forms, the FlowControl, displays a UserControl which has labels and a Picture box on.

Comment: I think you need to first cast it to a `PictureBox`. `flowProd.Controls["picture_product"]` is of type Control, so it does not have an Image property.

Comment: Please remove the misleading flow-control tag! Also correct the wrong tilte!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Controls in FlowControl is base type of control, you have to cast control to see all of properties.
exmaple:

```
((PictureBox)flowProd.Controls["picture_product"]).Image = Image.FromFile(filePath);
```